# How to designate the density function uniform distribution (continuous) on the set $[-1,0] \cup [3,5]$

Tags: probability, density-function

How to designate the density function uniform distribution (continuous) on the set $[-1,0] \cup [3,5]$?

I know how to do it when we only have for example [3,5] but for this set $[-1,0] \cup [3,5]$ I don't know. Please help me.

Comment: The same idea as for $[3,5]$ should work. You have to divide by the total length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total interval length for your uniform distribution is $3$, since the first interval has length $1$ and the second interval has length $2$. If it helps, you can think of the uniform density in your problem as isomorphic to a uniform density on $[0,3]$.
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1/3 & x \in [-1,0] \cup [3,5] \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Note that alignment tabs work in "cases".  I added them and expunged the "\quad"s. $\qquad$

Comment: So when I want count $E(X) = \int_{-1}^{0} 1/3x + \int_{3}^{5} 1/3x $ ?

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks for the fix! I hadn't thought about doing that.

Comment: @zxc Yes, I would think so. Intuitively, the mean here should be 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

The density function of the uniform distribution on $K$ is given by $f(x)=\frac{1}{m(K)}1\!\!1_{K}(x)$. Where $m(K)$ is the measure of $K$.

The measure of the union of the two intervalls is $2+1=3$. So the density function is given by : 
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{3}1\!\!1_{[-1,0] \cup [3,5]}(x)$$

Comment: When I want count $E(X) = \int_{-1}^{0} 1/3x + \int_{3}^{5} 1/3x $ ? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that's it. ${}$

Comment: @zxc $\mathsf E(X) = \int_{-1}^{0} \tfrac 1 3x\operatorname d x + \int_{3}^{5} \tfrac 1 3 x\operatorname d x$  to be correct (though I assume that is what you meant and just misse the 'dx's)